# How to call API in Discord.NET command?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, discord.net

I have problem with calling API in my Discord Bot, I am trying to learn async, await but it seems as I am stuck.

This is my Call API class where I am calling API.

```
public async Task<Root> GetInfoAsync()
    {
        string path = "https://onemocneni-aktualne.mzcr.cz/api/v2/covid-19/zakladni-prehled.json";
        Root data = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public async Task<string> VypisAsync()
    {
        Root data = await this.GetInfoAsync();
        int deaths = data.data[0].umrti,
            recovered = data.data[0].vyleceni,
            positive = data.data[0].aktivni_pripady,
            hospitalized = data.data[0].aktualne_hospitalizovani;
        return $"Aktualni situace v ČR:\n" +
               $"vyleceni: {recovered}\n"  +
               $"aktualne nemocni: {positive}\n" +
               $"hospitalizovani: {hospitalized}\n" +
               $"zemreli: {deaths}";
    }
```

And here is my covid command

```
public class CovidModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    // ~void -> current covid situation in CZ
    [Command("covid")]
    [Summary("shows current covid situation in CZ")]
    public async Task<Task> CovidAsync()
    {
        CovidApi api = new CovidApi();
        return ReplyAsync(await api.VypisAsync());
    }
}
```

I know that all others commands return Task, but I don't know how to make it like that.

Comment: What is CovidAsync() supposed to return? Is it supposed to wait for some data and return that?

Comment: It is supposed to reply to user after his command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReplyAsync()` is an async method, so you need to await it.

Your `CovidAsync()` method isn't returning an actual value, so in the synchronous world its return value would be `void`. Since it's an async method you return `Task` instead.

```
public async Task CovidAsync()
{
    CovidApi api = new CovidApi();
    await ReplyAsync(await api.VypisAsync());
}
```

As an aside, it would be better to have `CovidApi` as a member of your `CovidModule`. That way you don't need to keep newing it up in each method.

Comment: Thank you, it was that.